# Selecting Columns from Dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe with many many columns.  I want to reduce this dataframe to one with only the columns I require.

Instead of using

```
del df['column_name']
```

for all the columns that I don't need, is there a way to select the ones I do and create a new dataframe? I have tried:

```
df1['column_name'] = df['column_name']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the columns in a list:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df[cols]
```

Comment: I don't understand why this works and this does not:

    'df = df[['col1', 'col2']]'